# derivation path for ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, wallets, evm, hd-wallets

how are you doing! I would like to know what happens if from a ethereum seed I derive a wallet using BIP49, BIP84 derivation path and then send ethereum from another wallet which is BIP32 or BIP44, what will happen ?

because BIP49 starts with 3, and BIP84 with bc1,
I know they are related paths to BTC but in etherum It will work then?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum commonly uses `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`, but you can use other derivation paths. Using a BIP-49 or BIP-84 (segwit) derivation path works just like normal, assuming that you have an application that can derive Ethereum addresses from one of those paths. In the end, you still have a normal Ethereum address where you can send ETH to.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for the response i thought that it will generate an error by EVM or nodes and  even lost of etherum because of different path, thanks.

Comment: An Ethereum address is just a hash of the public key (which is derived from the private key). Even with the different paths, you still end up with a regular Ethereum address. Bitcoin's address generation is different from Ethereum, so with Bitcoin you get different address types with the different paths.